# Calculated field returning same value SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an issue with the below sub-query:

```
(select AVG(retail) 
 from STOCK 
 where category = 'TOYOTA' or category = 'HONDA') as AVERAGE_SALE_PRICE
```

Entire query:

```
select 
    d.name, s.category,(select AVG(retail) 
    where category = 'TOYOTA' or category = 'HONDA') as  AVERAGE_SALE_PRICE
from dealer d join stock s using (dealerID)
```

The issue is that this calculated field returns the same value for all the rows in the query, I understand that I may have add a GROUP BY but I am quite confused where...

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should join STOCK table with your driving table in main select.

Comment: Can you post the ddl for these tree tables. Is there foreign key between stock and dealer, stock and tower?

Comment: @StefanYordanov i seem to have made a mistake i am joining stock and the dealer table, both of these have dealerID as a key

Comment: @StefanYordanov basically i want to display the dealer name, the stock category, and a calculated field which finds the avg retail price for the two selected brands in the category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select AVG(retail) as AVERAGE_SALE_PRICE, category
from STOCK 
where category='TOYOTA' or category='HONDA'
group by category
```

> Update.This should give you the desired results:

```
select 
    d.name, 
    s.category,
    (select AVG(s.retail) 
     from stock s1 
     where s1.dealerID = s.dealerID 
           and (s1.category = 'TOYOTA' or s1.category = 'HONDA') as AVERAGE_SALE_PRICE 
from dealer d 
join stock s using (dealerID)
```

Comment: Could i wrap this as a nested sub-query? Because i cant seem to use that complete query while I am using a table join

Comment: I think no. You should join STOCK table with you driving table in you main query. Add more info for you use-case.